# Deploy OSM vector tiles in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, vector-tiles, pbf

I'm playing around a bit with Mapbox Vector Tiles as part of my bachelor thesis and would like to deploy them via a local server.

Setup (realized with DOCKER):

PostGIS DB --> OSM data
Geoserver with VektorTiles extension --> outputs data
QGis --> test client

So far the whole thing works quite well. But I have the following questions:

How can I output the data in the usual OSM style?
In the GeoServer I have to decide between line, point or polygon and I only pass one category of data to QGIS.

Has anyone ever implemented this?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)